# Custom UI Editor Word - Property of RichText content Control

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to create a Ribbon which replicates 2 buttons from the Developer tab:
- RichText Content Control
- Properties button (only available when a RichText Content Control exists).

So far, I've the following code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab id="MyCustomTab" label="Investor Force" insertAfterMso="Add-Ins">
<group id="customGroup1" label="Controls">
<button id="customButton1" imageMso="ContentControlRichText" onAction="RichText" />
<separator id="separator" />
<button id="customButton11" imageMso="PropertySheet" label="Properties" onAction="DocumentProperties" />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

However, I can't open the Properties when the RichText box is selected. Anyone can help me?

Thanks,